# In response function in ajax the variable is stated undefined

Tags: ajax, flask

I have just started learning the ajax thing and was trying to get a model like: it will show hello world and hello flask alternatively with pressing the enter key and is stuck in the following circumstances

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $
        (document).keydown(function(event){
            if(event.key==='Enter'){
                event.preventDefault();
                toggleContent();
            }
        });

        function toggleContent(){
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url:'/',
                    type:'POST',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    data:JSON.stringify({'content':$('#content').text()}),
                    success:function(response){
                        $('#content').text(response.content);
                        console.log(response.content)
                    },
                    error:function(error){console.log(error);}
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="content">Hello! flask</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In the success function the content part is giving undefined but in the python file it is returning a content variable.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method=='POST':
        content=request.get_json().get('content')
        print("request"+content) 
        if content=='Hello! flask':
            content='Hello! world'
            print(content+"1")
        else:
            content='Hello! flask'
            print(content+"2")
    else:
        content='Hello! flask'
        print(content+"3")
    return render_template('index.html',content=content)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=1)
```

This is the python file.

I have added many print statements to know which if-else statements are working. Plz help

Comment: `response` will be an HTML string which does not have a `content` property

Comment: Then can you plz show how to return the content to tha java script